# Why are previous views that have been popped from the stack still active

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have this truck driving app in swiftUI where I use fire base to log users in and out. The problem is that when I sign in with one user, and all it’s fire base functionalities are triggered, After I log out from the current user and into a new user, the functionality of the old user is still playing out. I think it might have something to do with the firebase functions being in an  onAppear method. I am not sure though.

This is the firebase code. I dont think what Im querying has any relation to the solution so I wont explain it but if you think it does than please let me know.

```
        .onAppear(perform: {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (_,_) in
            
        }
   
            myDrivers = []
              getEmails()
        
        db.collectionGroup("resources").whereField("control", isEqualTo: true).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, err) in
            
            if myDrivers.count == 0{}
            
            else{
            
            if err != nil{print("Error fetching motion status: \(err)")}
            
            if ((snapshot?.documents.isEmpty) != nil){}
```

//                Gets all the driverLocation documents

```
            for doc in snapshot!.documents{
                
                if myDrivers.contains(doc.reference.parent.parent!.documentID){
              
                let isDriving = doc.get("isDriving") as! Bool
                let isStopped = doc.get("isStopped") as! Bool
                let notified = doc.get("notified") as! Bool
                
                if (isDriving == false && isStopped == false) || notified{}
                
                else{
```

//                        Gets the name of the drivers

```
                    doc.reference.parent.parent?.getDocument(completion: { (snapshot, err) in
                        
                        if err != nil{print("Error parsing driver name: \(err)")}
                        
                        let firstName = snapshot?.get("firstName") as! String
                        let lastName = snapshot?.get("lastName") as! String
                        
                        self.notifiedDriver = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
            
                    })
```

//                    Logic

```
                    if isDriving{
                        
                        send(notiTitle: "MyFleet", notiBody: "\(notifiedDriver) is back on the road.")
                        showDrivingToast.toggle()
                        doc.reference.updateData(["notified" : true])
                        
                    }else if isStopped{

                       send(notiTitle: "MyFleet", notiBody: "\(notifiedDriver) has stopped driving.")
                        showStoppedToast.toggle()
                        doc.reference.updateData(["notified" : true])
                        
                    }
                }
            }
                else{}    
            }

        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listeners don't die when a view controller is left. They remain active.

It's important to manage them through handlers for specific listeners as a view closes or the user navigates away. Here's how to [remove a specific listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener)

```
let listener = db.collection("cities").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
    // ...
}
```

and then later

```
// Stop listening to changes
listener.remove()
```

Or, if your user is logging out, you can use [removeAllObservers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#-removeallobservers) (for the RealtimeDatabase) to remove them all at one time, noting that

> removeAllObservers must be called again for each child reference where
> a listener was established

For Firestore, store the listeners in a listener array class var and when you want to remove them all, just iterate over the array elements calling .remove() on each.

There's additional info in the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Detach Listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#detach_listeners)

Comment: Hey Jay im just checking the links you provided. Unfortunately, the remove all listeners function only works for FirebaseDatabase. Is there any way I can remove all listeners in FirebaseFirestore or do I have to just use a reference for each one.

Comment: Could you take a look at this attempt of mine.

Comment: @MohamedElsayed Oh gosh - sorry about that. You are correct that link is for the Realtime Database only. With firestore you would generally add listeners to an array or listeners and if you want to remove them all, iterate over the handles in the array.